# Is content control object in header or footer countable?

Tags: wordpress, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I inserted content control in my word document header for all pages, but later I noticed that "contentcontrol.items.length" result is always 1. Shouldnt it equal to the page number? why it is alway one? Anyone can explain? Code:

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {  

        var mySections = context.document.sections;        
        context.load(mySections, 'body/style');
        await context.sync().then(function () {

          var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");
          myHeader.clear();

          myHeader.insertHtml('<a href="https://www.cgi.se/">CGI</a>',"Start");

          var myContentControl = myHeader.insertContentControl();
          myContentControl.tag = "header";
          myContentControl.appearance = "Tags"; 

          return context.sync();
        });
      });
```

Then to count content controls:

```
  async function ContentControlCount() {
    // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
    await Word.run(function (context) {

      // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
      var mySections = context.document.sections;

      // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
      context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

      return context.sync().then(function () {

        var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader('primary');
        return context.sync().then(function () {

          var contentControl = myHeader.contentControls;

          // Queue a command to load the text property for a content control.
          context.load(contentControl, 'text, tag');

          // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
          return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log(contentControl.items.length);
            console.log(contentControl.items[0].text);

          });
        });
      });

    })
      .catch(function (e) { console.log(e.message); })

  }
```

Comment: If this this a coding problem, then add your attempts so far. Otherwise, it should move to https://superuser.com/

Comment: code added, thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Now your question is a valuable contribution to our knowledge base.

Comment: Anyone can share some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's only one header per section. You should think of it as a template. Even though it renders on every page, it's still the same header object. So if you add a content control to it, that's just one content control, no matter how many pages are in the section.

Comment: Thank you Rick, now I see how this header works. I'm counting the content controls is actually to count page numbers, as the currect office APIs don't support page numbering, I was thinking maybe I can get headers number then I know page number, but obviously it doesn't work this way..